# How to declare friend method when class definitions cross reference?

Tags: c++, friend-function

I want to define two classes, A and B. A has a data member which is a Class B object and is in-class initialised. A also has a method to retrieve the value in this B type data member and this method would be declared as a friend method in B. Here is my code:

```
class A{
public:
    int getBValue();
private:
    B b=B(1);
};

class B{
public:
    friend int A::getBValue();
    B(int i):value(i){}
private:
    int value;
};

int A::getBValue(){
    return b.value;
}
```

And unsurprisingly the compilation had failed because of unknown type B in class A definition. I had tried to swap the definitions of A and B in the source and the result was even worse. Is there a possible way to resolve this cross reference issue between A and B?

Comment: What was the error when you declared B first? What happens if you only make the class 'A' as friend when switching the order? Anyway, why not have a public getter?

Comment: You can't make this without a compromise - either store a pointer to B instead of an instance and forward declare it, or give up on `friend` requirement and provide a getter instead.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Two errors. One is "use of undeclared identifier 'A'", the other is "'value' is a private member of 'B'".

Answer (score 3):

If this is the complete code as you have it, then the problem is that the compiler doesn't know what a `B` is at the time it is compiling class `A`. One way to solve it is by creating a pointer to B instead of having a B itself:

**A.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_A
#define CLASS_A

class B;

class A{
public:
    int getBValue();
private:
    B *b;
};

#endif
```

**B.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_B
#define CLASS_B

#include "A.h"

class B{
public:
    friend int A::getBValue();
    B(int i):value(i){}
private:
    int value;
};

#endif
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int A::getBValue(){
    return b->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing an embedded member of type `B` with a pointer (or reference) to a `B` changes the way your class works and needs additional care when copying objects of class `A`.

When you reverse the definitions, you cannot make a member function of class `A` a friend of class `B`, because the type of `A` is incomplete at the time of the `friend` declaration. But you can make the entire class `A` a friend.

A solution with class `A` having an embedded member of class `B` could look like this:

```
class A;

class B{
public:
    friend class A;
    B(int i):value(i){}
private:
    int value;
};

class A{
public:
    int getBValue();
private:
    B b=B(1);
};

int A::getBValue(){
    return b.value;
}
```

Changes made:

1. Declared `B` before `A`. A forward declaration for `A` is used.
2. Made the *class* `A` a friend of `B`. This works even when `A` is not yet fully defined.

Compiles with g++ version 4.7.2 (-std=c++11 needed for `B b=B(1);`)

Anyway, having a member of class `A` accessing a private member of class `B` is something which can (and should) almost always be avoided (see Laszlo Papp's comment on your post).